# User login with PHP and MySQLi not working

Tags: php, authentication, mysqli

I've got a simple form to register users that works perfectly. Now I'm trying to log in with any registered user but I can't make it work. I've been reading a while about people with the same problem but I can't find a solution.

Here's my code:

connection.inc.php

```
    <?php

$name = 'pruser';
$pwd = 'pruser';
$dbname = 'project1db';
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", $name, $pwd, $dbname);
```

login.php

```
    <?php
include('connection.inc.php');
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    session_start();
    $username = trim($_POST['user']);
    $password = trim(sha1($_POST['pass']));

    // check user in db
    $sql = "SELECT user, pwd FROM users WHERE user = ? AND pwd = ? LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    if ($stmt === false) {
        echo 'Error';
    }
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $password);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($username, $password);
    echo $stmt->num_rows;
    $stmt->close();
}
?>


<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Log in - Project 1</title>
</head>
<body>

<form id="form1" method="post" action="">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Log in</legend>
        <p>
            <label for="user">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="user" id="user">
            <label for="pass">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass">
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="Log in">
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>

<a href="register.php">Register</a/>
</body>
</html>
```

When I check how many rows are affected the result is -1. After loging in I want it to redirect to index.php. That's not a problem, but first I need to log in.

Comment: Doesn't work. In the DB there's another table for the ID so I think I can't use *.

Comment: And what about `$sql = "SELECT user, pass FROM users WHERE user = ? AND pass = ? LIMIT 1";` I'm confused. Your "password" field is associated with `pass` and `pwd` and `$password`

Comment: pwd is how it's called in the db. pass is just the name in the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling `$stmt->store_result();` right after `$stmt->execute();`

Answer (score 0):

```
      $sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE user = ? AND pwd = ? LIMIT 1";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        if ($stmt === false) {
            echo 'Error';
        }
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $password);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($count);
        $stmt->fetch;
        $stmt->close();
        if($count > 0){
## login OK
        } else {
## login false
        }
```